# Could not find a navbar background that fits with my logo

Tags: website-design, interface-design

I recently changed the logo for my company but now it does not fit anymore on the navbar. The color of the logo are  #3331a1 and #a8b0c6. I don't really want to have a white navbar but seems to be the only option. I am also willing to modify a bit the color of the "HR". Do you have any suggestions for the navbar color?

[image: my logo]
[image: current navbar]

Answer (score 2):

Logos *should* generally have multiple approved configurations for various use cases..... 1 color, reversed, greyscale, processes color, spot color.

In this instance I would merely change the logo to a one-color version. And in white for this use.